# Docker / Docker compose sometimes cannot be reached

Tags: docker, flask

I started with docker some time ago and i started to have some problems.
First, i created an image with Ubuntu running an flask service and i have a app in my local pc that i connect to that flask throw the port 5000 "localhost:5000", the app works fine

I decided to create a load balancing app using the nginx and creating 2 instances of my flask service
using docker compose and everything goes fine and when i type localhost:5000 in my browser i am able to see that is working but when i try to use it within my local app it does not respond.

Can be a problem with the network or i am missing something.
Regards and sorry for bad English.

Comment: "when i try to use it within my local app it does not respond". Can you please provide some code snippets on how you're trying to access it, and the response you get. Also your nginx config for the load balancing and your docker-compose.yml (assuming you're using compose) would be nice.

Comment: Nginx Docker-compose file
version: '3.7'
services:
    app:
        build: testapp
        restart: always                   
    nginx:
        container_name: nginx
        build: nginx
        ports:
            - 5000:5000
        depends_on:
           - app

Comment: I was just making some test and i realize that the problem was the way i run the container and not setting the same options in the compose file i was missing the -t in the compose file, i set it to tty:yes and fixed the problem